# sql function throwing error when one of its parameters range is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql function which i run using dynamic query.

**Dynamic query is:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * 
                       FROM Client_Report_Consol_Summary_RELATED1(@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14)
                      WHERE (WEEKNUM = @p4) AND  (YEAR = @p5) 
                   ORDER BY ProductDescription,ISSUE_DESC,ConsigneeFullName',
N'@p11 uniqueidentifier,
@p12 nvarchar(4000),
@p13 nvarchar(4000),
@p14 nvarchar(4000),
@p4 decimal(1,0),
@p5 decimal(4,0)',
@p11='F312F49B-203E-4BBA-A74E-82EA356ED6D3',
@p12=NULL,
@p13=N'',
@p14=N'',
@p4=1,      <-- seems to be the issue
@p5=2011
```

When i run the above i get below error
**Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.**

but when i edit my dynamic query and update  "**@p4 decimal(1,0)**" to "**@p4 decimal(2,0)**" it works fine.

Please can anyone throw some light on why is this happening.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WEEKNUM column coming out of your function is a string - and SQL server is trying to convert it to the numeric type so it can perform the comparison. So you either need to pass your param as a (n)varchar so that a string comparison occurs, or go with the fix you already have - make your numeric parameter large enough to accomodate any WEEKNUM value that will come out of this function.

I first created a dummy function that returned WEEKNUM as an int, but couldn't reproduce issue. The below function does demo the issue:

```
create function Client_Report_Consol_Summary_RELATED1 (
    @p11 uniqueidentifier,
@p12 nvarchar(4000),
@p13 nvarchar(4000),
@p14 nvarchar(4000)
)
returns table
as
    return (select '22' as WEEKNUM, 2011 as YEAR, 1 as ProductDescription,1 as ISSUE_DESC, 1 as ConsigneeFullName
    )
go
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a data loss in your type conversion to numeric types. For example -

If your varchar field has a value "123" and you are trying to convert it to DECIMAL(1,0), it obviously cant hold complete 123 value. Hence it throws above error.

Comment: Sachin, I agree with your point but i am only passing "1" as value to my @p4 variable, which i believe should be fine. please advise

Comment: @Amit - I tried to insert value of 1 into column with DECIMAL(1,0) and it worked fine. I am not sure why it is not working in your case. Ideally it should. Try @p4 = CAST('1' as DECIMAL(1,0))

Comment: It's the string coming out of the function in the WEEKNUM column that's failing to convert to decimal(1,0)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes. you are right. Now I get it too. Thanks.